# SharePoint Foundation-Compatible application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, error

I am using SharePoint 2013 enterprise. I m trying to export a list into excel its showing following error:

[image]

Comment: I get that from time to time and i think it always ends up with my repairing my local office install. Does it work for anyone around you?

Comment: Also, try it in IE, that looks like a Chrome error.

Comment: @Eric: it showing same at IE too...